# How to make item selector on spinner work

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-spinner

```
String [] product = new String [] {
            "Item A - 15$",
            "Item B - 12$",
            "item C - 30$",
            "Item D - 40$",

    };

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new
            ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,product);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            final Spinner spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            spin.setAdapter(adapter);

            spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l){
                    if(spin.getSelectedItem().equals(0))
                    {
                        Double addprice = 15.0;
                        Totalprice.setText(Double.toString(currentprice)+ 
                        Double.toString(addprice));
                    }
                }

              public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                    return;
                } 
            });
```

What I trying to do is when user select Item A from spinner, the Totalprice edittext box will add the price on it . For example , the current price is 0.0 and user select Item A ,it will become displaying 10.0. This apply to other Item as well, which meaning whenever user select any item, the price will auto add to Totalprice.

I successfully add the spinner but when I select any item on spinner and it just won't work, anyone can provide solution or other better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell why there is that if statement inside `onItemSelected()`. 
All you need to do is get the numeric value from the spinner, after parsing the text, 
 get the numeric value of the `EditText`, add the 2 values and set the total back to the `EditText`.

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l){
        String s  = adapterView
                .getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()
                .split("-")[1].trim()
                .replace("$", "");
        double addprice = Double.parseDouble(s);
        double currentprice = 0.0;
        try {
            currentprice = Double.parseDouble(Totalprice.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        double total = currentprice + addprice;
        Totalprice.setText(String.valueOf(total));
    }
```

Edit:
After this line:

```
spin.setAdapter(adapter);
```

set the `EditText`'s text to `0.0`:

```
Totalprice.setText("0.0");
```

Comment: I have an error (Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type double) at the last code there

Comment: but which part should i edit the calculation part? for example member will have 10% discount on total price

Comment: After `double total = currentprice + addprice;` make any calculations you want to the `total` and then with `Totalprice.setText(String.valueOf(total));` you set the new total to the EditText.

Comment: Ok, but i figured one problem here is when user just loaded the page, the total price already is 15 since Item A is default selected. How do i solve this?

Comment: Is that also possible that when user click Item A 1 time and Item B 3 time. I use textview to display Item A = 1 and Item B =3 which let user know what item they clicked.

Comment: This is already the 4th question you ask that has nothing to do with the original question. This is not how it works here in SO. Post a new question where you explain what the problem is and all the code you have so far.